# Button not firing after getting formatted text from WYSIWYG Text Editor while works fine in informatted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

I am using WYSIWYG Text Editor with Jquery and Bootstrap. When I try to get unformatted text at button click it works fine but when try to get formatted text it does not even fire at server side.

```
function customEditor() 
{
  $("#tbNewsEditor").Editor();
}
```

Onclient click event getText from editor and saved in hidden field no exception is being occured in this function.

```
 function NewsEditorText() 
    {
      try
      {
        var newsEditorText = $("#tbNewsEditor").Editor("getText");

        alert(newsEditorText);

        document.getElementById('<%=hfNewsEditorText.ClientID %>').value =    
        newsEditorText;

        alert(document.getElementById('<%=hfNewsEditorText.ClientID %>').value);

      }
      catch (e) 
      {

      }
         return true;   
      }

        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbNewsEditor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 <asp:HiddenField ID="hfNewsEditorText" runat="server" />
                 <asp:Button ID="btnNewsEditor" runat="server" Text="Button" 
                  OnClientClick="return NewsEditorText()"  
                  OnClick="btnNewsEditor_Click"/>
            </div>
          </div>

         protected void btnNewsEditor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string newsEditorText = hfNewsEditorText.Value;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
```

At page load Called the Javascript function customEditor which successfully load the editor.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "customEditor", "customEditor();", true);

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

               //TODO 
            }
        }
```

I am unable to figure out how its working fine in unformatted text while in the case of formatted text button does not fire. I am getting simple text but IN case of formatted text (html) button does not fire.